# Change cell value as per condition

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I have a LibreOffice Calc file where I want to change a field as per the drop down box.

```
=IF(O5="Buy", P5=P5*-1, P5=P5*1)
```

Here O5 cell is my dropdown list box and P5 is impact cell as per buy or sell from drop down. I have written above code by selecting O5 cell Format Menu->Conditional Formating->Condition. Selected "Formula is", but it does not changes the value in P5.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 1):

As pnuts said, you don't use Conditional Formatting for this. You could write a macro to change the value at P5, but I think the easiest way to accomplish what you want would be to have the absolute valor at P5 and the "actual" (either negative or positive) value at a different cell (say, Q5). The formula at Q5 would be:

```
=IF(O5="Buy"; P5*-1; P5)
```

I'm all for writing macros but, in this particular case, I don't think it's worth it. I'd go for this solution.